# Spawned child exits with state = 127

Tags: c++, spawn, waitpid

I use posix_spawnp to execute different processes and I check the status (with waitpid) to make sure the child was created properly

```
    int iRet = posix_spawnp(&iPID, zPath, NULL, NULL, argv, environ);       

    if (iRet != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int iState;
    waitpid(static_cast<pid_t>(iPID), &iState, WNOHANG);
    cout << "Wait: PID " << iPID << " | State " << iState << endl;

    if (WIFEXITED(iState)) {
        printf("Child exited with RC=%d\n",WEXITSTATUS(iState));
    }
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(iState)) {
        printf("Child exited via signal %d\n",WTERMSIG(iState));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Child is NORMAL");
    }
```

At first this executes properly and I get the following message:

> Wait: PID 15911 | State 0 Child exited
>   with RC=0

After executing the same process several times, the child process starts to exit with status 127.

> Wait: PID 15947 | State 32512 Child
>   exited with RC=127

After this happens, I could not get the child to spawn again. I enclosed the section of code given above in a for loop but it wouldn't spawn properly.
If I restart the parent process, it works for a while but the same problem crops up again after a while.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/posix_spawn.htm).

For example:

> EINVAL    The value specified by file_actions or attrp is invalid.
>
> The error codes for the posix_spawn and posix_spawnp subroutines are affected by the following conditions:
>   If this error occurs after the calling process successfully returns from the posix_spawn or posix_spawnp function, the child process might exit with exit status 127.

It looks as if it might exit with 127 for a whole host of reasons.

Comment: I re-wrote the code using fork and execvp to get a more definite grasp of the error and it turned out that the actual error info is:
errno = 14 (bad address)
Some digging around revealed that this was because I wasn't ending my argument list with a final entry of "NULL".

argv = new char[iSize + 1];

argv[iSize] = NULL;


fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return code from `waitpid()` to be sure that it isn't having problems.

The way the code reads suggests that you are only spawning one child process at a time (otherwise there'd be no need to call `waitpid()` within the loop).  However in that case I wouldn't expect to use `WNOHANG`.

Comment: The waitpid call returns with a value > 0 which means that there's a valid child.